# DictVectorizer in sklearn gives error in python 3.4

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.4

I have been trying to invokethe DictVectorizer in sklearn.feature_extraction.

```
import numpy
import scipy
import sklearn
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
```

However it gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .dict_vectorizer import DictVectorizer
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ..utils import check_array, tosequence
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import in1d
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 318, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Can anyone please help me out in figuring out what's going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any problem with any other class? Have you tried sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher? Which version of scikit do you use?

Comment: Hi, sorry about the delay in response.I am using the scikit learn version - 0.16.1. Even FeatureHasher throws up the same error

Comment: Did you install it from source or by conda?

Comment: I got the wheel file from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Comment: Check my answer for advice on your installation

Answer (score 0):

I got similar Error while using an installation of python that wasn't linked to scikit. Please be sure that your scikit installation is ok and that you use the python version that is linked to scikit-learn.

You can check it in command line by entering python command and importing the package.

Be sure to have [the prerequisite](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/install.html) for Scikit-learn too.

EDIT:

After reading your comment, you should probably go to official install. You can use [the official website documentation for installation on Windows](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/install.html#windows) or use [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads#34). Anaconda is a all-in-one solution maybe easier to install. It is quite safe as it is approve by some of the core developpers of sklearn.

Should always avoid unofficial or undocumented installation.

Comment: I have ensured that the prerequisites are in place